# If INSERT IGNORE echo "Query was ignored"? (mysql/php)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I have a query like this:

```
$query="INSERT IGNORE INTO mytable (key, word1, word2) VALUES (1, 'abc', 'def')";
```

And I'd like to somehow "catch" if the query was ignored because the primary key already exists.

Is there any was to make an "if" statement so my program could notify the user that the query was ignored?

Comment: Can you post more context than just the one line?  PHP does support control logic, but without seeing how the results of your query are going to be applied it's difficult to determine a correct solution.

Comment: Isn't it better to do a normal insert and check for the error instead? Also keep in mind that "If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are ignored." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by using `mysql_affected_rows` to check if no rows were affected by the query.

```
    if($productquery&&mysql_affected_rows($conn)>0){

    echo "Success.";    
    echo mysql_affected_rows($conn); //returns 1

}else{

    echo "Some error." . mysql_error(). " ".mysql_affected_rows($conn); //returns 0 affected rows since it was ignored

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you especially ignore the errors then you don't get them. So you have to remove the **IGNORE** and catch the error instead.

You don't get any errors in your case.